# Why are my css elements larger than other examples?

Tags: css, tailwind-css, daisyui

I am not a designer, and for my side hustles, I do a lot of cutting and pasting.  I'm sure I'm not alone.  I'm currently building out a personal project using tailwindcss, appwrite, and sveltekit.

If I find something I like and want to borrow in a tutorial or wherever invariably my pasted example is always larger than the tutorial.  Inspecting the CSS shows the same WxH in pixels, so it is like my pixel is larger somehow?  For example, here I've pasted some buttons taken off of the daisyUI component example site: https://daisyui.com/components/button

I've copied the html verbatim from daisyUI.  I thought maybe there was a different base font size, but I copied out the styles from my site and daisyUI then ran a diff, which showed nothing substantive (that I'm aware of).  Also, it is this way on every site whether some codepen or the tailwindcss site.  The example below shows they are both 64x64; however, mine is substantially larger.

It is possible that svelte is somehow adding to this situation, but I don't know how that could be.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So, uh, a little embarrassed but it finally dawned on me, do I have this viewport zoomed? And, uh, yeah, I did.  Setting it back to 100% made the world a better place.

Comment: Live and learn ^^